# Removing Location Keyframes from LocRotScale?

Tags: keyframes

I am working on a Minecraft animation with the ender dragon.  I first made sure that the flying was correct before I did anything else and by habit i used LocRotScale when setting the keyframes.  Is there a way to convert LocRotScale to just RotScale, removing the location keyframes?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in Graph Editor. Disable visibility of all other channels and delete keyframes on the channels you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try opening the *graph editor* with your dragon selected, and go through the drop down menus for it and see f there is a separate key frame sequence for location. If there is, you can select it and delete with `x`. I'm sorry I don't have access to a computer at the moment otherwise I would provide screenshots and a less vague answer. I will update this when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the "location" box in the object panel and choose "Clear Keyframes". If there's a keyframe on the current frame, you will also have a "delete keyframe" option which deletes only the key on the current frame (location keys on other frames will be left alone. "Clear keyframes" wipes out all of them)